# I cannot see the files in some folders. How can I access them?

Tags: 11.10, filesystem

I am totally new to Ubuntu so please excuse me for my ignorance. I've just installed Ubuntu on my Windows Vista laptop (to another partition). I have an separate partition were I've stored my data files (directory etc.).

I can successfully see the folders in that directory but not actually the files within them. I know that these directories are not empty.

EDIT:
I would like to clarify my question. I have 3 partitions. A: MS Vista, B: Ubuntu, C:MyData
While I am in Vista I can access everything in C:MyData. However, in Ubuntu despite that I can see and navigate in folder structure of C:MyData (eg, Pictures, Movies, Documents etc) all folders appears empty. I've tried to go to view (hidden / unhidden) files but it not works:(

What is the problem?

Comment: can you access the partition and see the content from Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a question of permissions. Go on the windows partition and check if the folders are protected and who can see. You may add "everyone" to the list of those who can access the files. (File,Properties,Sharing/Security)

You may also try to try to check if you can access files in Ubuntu as root:

- Press **Alt+F2**
- Type **gksu nautilus**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Nautilus to view files/folders, click "Edit", "Prefrences" and then select "Show hidden and backup files" under the "View" tab.

Nautilus is like Vista's File explorer. The easiest path to it in Unity is to select the Home Folder on the Launcher.